# How do I fix Parse-MS not working on Discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am in the process of developing a discord economy bot, and I was following a tutorial for a beg command, but I am running into issues with making the cooldown for it with parse-ms

I also need help making timeEmbed display the cooldown time left because right now it displays as **undefined** minutes **undefined** seconds

Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");
const ms = require("parse-ms");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith('m!'))return;  

  const user = message.author;

  const timeout = 180000;
  const amount = 5;

  const beg = await db.fetch(`beg_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);

  if (beg !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - beg) > 0) {
    const time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - beg));
  
    const timeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#FFFFFF")
    .setDescription(`<:Cross:618736602901905418> You've already begged recently\n\nBeg again in ${time.minutes} minutes ${time.seconds} seconds`);
    message.channel.send(timeEmbed)
  } else {
    const moneyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("#FFFFFF")
  .setDescription(`<:Check:618736570337591296> You've begged and received ${amount} coins`);
  message.channel.send(moneyEmbed)
  db.add(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, amount)
  db.set(`beg_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())


  }
};


module.exports.help = {
  name:"beg",
  aliases: [""]
}
```

Comment: you should debug more what is `time`, `beg` look like did your db get it successful

Comment: Do you have `parse-ms` installed correctly? Try uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This Command In Shell "npm install parse-ms-2"

```
const db = require("quick.db");
const ms = require("parse-ms-2");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith('m!'))return;  

  const user = message.author;

  const timeout = 180000;
  const amount = 5;

  const beg = await db.fetch(`beg_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);

  if (beg !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - beg) > 0) {
    const time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - beg));
  
    const timeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#FFFFFF")
    .setDescription(`<:Cross:618736602901905418> You've already begged recently\n\nBeg again in ${time.minutes} minutes ${time.seconds} seconds`);
    message.channel.send(timeEmbed)
  } else {
    const moneyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("#FFFFFF")
  .setDescription(`<:Check:618736570337591296> You've begged and received ${amount} coins`);
  message.channel.send(moneyEmbed)
  db.add(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, amount)
  db.set(`beg_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())


  }
};


module.exports.help = {
  name:"beg",
  aliases: [""]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change your file name extension to .mjs instead of .js and change the
front const to import.
for the other const that you will be using in the future stil remain
The full code:

```
import Discord from "discord.js";
import db from "quick.db";
import ms from "parse-ms";

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
if(!message.content.startsWith('m!'))return;  

const user = message.author;

const timeout = 180000;
const amount = 5;

const beg = await db.fetch(`beg_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);

if (beg !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - beg) > 0) {
const time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - beg));

const timeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor("#FFFFFF")
.setDescription(`<:Cross:618736602901905418> You've already begged 
recently\n\nBeg again in ${time.minutes} minutes ${time.seconds} seconds`);
message.channel.send(timeEmbed)
} else {
const moneyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor("#FFFFFF")
.setDescription(`<:Check:618736570337591296> You've begged and received 
${amount} coins`);
message.channel.send(moneyEmbed)
db.add(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, amount)
db.set(`beg_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())


}
};
```

Comment: Why not useful?